# Getting the top count of records from a table for each month and user

Tags: mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where translations are stored along with the `user_id` and when the translation was added.
I want to create a query that shows the 'Translator of the month' (the person who did the most translations in that month).

I have a query to get the top translator of all translations:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) 
FROM gp_translations
WHERE (STATUS='current' OR STATUS='old')
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(user_id)
```

and I have a query that shows the year/month:

```
SELECT distinct CONCAT(YEAR(`date_added`),'/', MONTH(`date_added`)) AS `Year/Month` 
FROM `gp_translations` t1
GROUP BY YEAR(`date_added`), MONTH(`date_added`)
ORDER BY `date_added` DESC
```

but when combining both I fail miserably. The query runs endlessly:

```
SELECT distinct CONCAT(YEAR(`date_added`),'/', MONTH(`date_added`)) AS `Year/Month`, (
SELECT distinct user_id
FROM gp_translations t2
WHERE (STATUS='current' OR STATUS='old') AND     YEAR(t2.date_added)=YEAR(t1.date_added)
AND MONTH(t2.date_added)=MONTH(t1.date_added)
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC
LIMIT 1)
FROM `gp_translations` t1
GROUP BY YEAR(`date_added`), MONTH(`date_added`)
ORDER BY `date_added` DESC
```

The table `gp_translations` has the following structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE `gp_translations` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`original_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`translation_set_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`translation_0` TEXT NOT NULL,
`translation_1` TEXT NULL,
`translation_2` TEXT NULL,
`translation_3` TEXT NULL,
`translation_4` TEXT NULL,
`translation_5` TEXT NULL,
`user_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`status` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'waiting',
`date_added` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`date_modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`warnings` TEXT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `original_id` (`original_id`),
INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
INDEX `translation_set_id` (`translation_set_id`),
INDEX `translation_set_id_status` (`translation_set_id`, `status`),
INDEX `date_added` (`date_added`),
INDEX `warnings` (`warnings`(1))
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=342587;
```

I know I am doing something seriously wrong here. But I can't find the way to properly merge both with decent speed. Any help is appreciated. MySQL version is 5.5.34

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of windows functions and cte, mysql version is quite verbose, but I hope it will give you desired results in reasonable time (I know it's not fast at all):

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM 
(
   SELECT yr,mn, MAX(translations_per_month) as max_user_translations
   FROM
   (
     SELECT  YEAR(`date_added`) as yr, MONTH(`date_added`) as mn, user_id, 
     COUNT(1) as translations_per_month
     FROM `gp_translations` t1
     INNER JOIN gp_users u ON 
      (u.id = t1.user_id AND u.STATUS='current' OR u.STATUS='old')
     GROUP BY  YEAR(`date_added`), MONTH(`date_added`),user_id
    )b
    GROUP BY yr,mn
)a
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT  YEAR(`date_added`) as yr, MONTH(`date_added`) as mn, user_id, display_name,
   COUNT(1) as translations_per_month
   FROM `gp_translations` t1
   INNER JOIN gp_users u ON (u.id = t1.user_id AND u.STATUS='current' OR u.STATUS='old')
   GROUP BY YEAR(`date_added`), MONTH(`date_added`),user_id, display_name
)c ON  (c.yr = a.yr and c.mn = a.mn and c.translations_per_month = a.max_user_translations)
```

Also, I made a guess that `status` column is in `gb_users` table ; if not, the query needs to be modified a bit.

Comment: Thank you but this query still does not finish. Note: The 'status' field is a field in gp_translations, but that's not the problem. The gp_translation table has about 240k entries. I added mored details on the table and mysql version.

Comment: @Deckard: Can you post result of `EXPLAIN` for queries? From table definitions I can tell the query will benefit from composite index on `gp_translations(user_id,date_added,status)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this query or even if I understood your question correctly. But if you need a query that shows the 'Translator of the month' (Top Translator per month).

```
SELECT CONCAT(yr,'/', mnt) AS `Year/Month`,user_id,totalTrans
FROM             
(                
    SELECT YEAR(date_added) as yr ,MONTH(date_added)as mnt, user_id, COUNT(1) AS totalTrans 
    FROM gp_translations
    WHERE (STATUS='current' OR STATUS='old')
    GROUP BY yr,mnt,user_id
    ORDER BY totalTrans DESC
)a               
GROUP BY yr,mnt ;
```

This query should be faster but it still does not utilize your indexes. 
Note that, if in one month two users have translated same number of document, only one of them will be shown.

Answer (score -3):

use rank and partition,
partition by year/month and rank order by count(user id)
then you have users by they rank(translation count) in each partition(year/month)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962950/sql-rank-over-partition-on-joined-tables

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: I'm afraid this suggestion is irrelevant for this question, because the OP is using MySQL, where ranking functions are not supported.